# Slash commands produce "interaction failed" when invoked in chat?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using the discord-py-slash-command library and have setup my commands. However when I type my command in the chat I get interaction failed each time. I have given my bot the correct scope and reinvited it to the server several times. Can someone take a look at my code an tell me what is going on? I have followed several tutorials with no luck.

```
TOKEN = open("./token.txt", "r").readline()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot, sync_commands=True)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to the Discord!')


@slash.slash(name="test", description='Test slash command activated', guild_ids= 
[928451150515150890])
async def test(ctx: SlashContext):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Embed Test")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Your code worked perfect for me, did you do the following? 1. imported all the needed modules 2. Started your bot using `bot.run(TOKEN)` 3. The guild ID is the right one.

Comment: This code has no reason to not work. Did you invite your bot with application.commands permission (from the OAuth url generator at Discord Developers page)?
Is your system too overloaded for whatever reason or network connection too slow, per the protocol if the bot doesn't respond within 3 seconds it says Interaction failed, but you can use `ctx.defer` method to increase that time

Comment: I am certain I imported everything. Yes I did the OAuth generator settings multiple times (re-inviting my bot each time). Network connection should not be an issue. Also ctx.defer() does not fix my issues unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I am editing my answer because at the time I was not sure what library you were using.

Your code works just fine, however, If you are going to use `intents=discord.Intents.all()`

you need to be sure to enable presence as well as server members intents in the developer console of the bot.

If you do not need to use intents for your application, disable them and set it to `intents=discord.Intents.default()`

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to implement Slash commands.

Comment: At the time, I did not catch what library OP was using. Thanks for the heads up. I have made corrections to my answer. Tested it on my end and it works just fine.

Comment: Made that change to my code, thanks. However I still get the interaction failed message. The slash command from my script shows up on the server. i can see it in the list of commands and use it but it fails each time. At this point I am not sure where the disconenct it

Comment: Let's do a test, Kick the bot from your server. Go back to discord developer portal and click oauth url generator. Select bot and applications.commands under scopes. and for roles, just give it full administrator access for now. add the bot back to your server with that link and then test it again.

Comment: I have tried that multiple times with the same results. I also used a simple print statement at the beginning of the test() method to see if it was being fired. It wasn't. The strange thing is that the command shows up in the discord chat but code behind it isn't being ran. So I know that discord is registering the slash command, but the underlying code is not being executed

Answer (score 0):

i switched over to the nextcord library for slash commands and the behavior is working as expected... I will consider this closed